# How to achive this effect on hover instead of on click?

Tags: javascript, mouseevent, event-listener

I found this really cool WebGL fluid simulation on [Github](https://github.com/PavelDoGreat/WebGL-Fluid-Simulation). For my project, I would need to start the animation on hover and not on mousedown.

I tried moving the code from the mousedown listener to the mousemove listener, but it didn't work.
I also searched for issues on Github, but only found solutions for an older version of the code that were no longer useful.

Here are the event listeners:

```
canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', e => {
    let posX = scaleByPixelRatio(e.offsetX);
    let posY = scaleByPixelRatio(e.offsetY);
    let pointer = pointers.find(p => p.id == -1);
    if (pointer == null)
        pointer = new pointerPrototype();
    updatePointerDownData(pointer, -1, posX, posY);
});

canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
    let pointer = pointers[0];
    if (!pointer.down) return;
    let posX = scaleByPixelRatio(e.offsetX);
    let posY = scaleByPixelRatio(e.offsetY);
    updatePointerMoveData(pointer, posX, posY);
});

window.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
    updatePointerUpData(pointers[0]);
});
```

Comment: [mouseover](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseover_event) event?

Answer (score 0):

Use "mouseover" event

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseover_event

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use onmouseover event listener i.e

```
object.addEventListener("mouseover", myScript);
```

In your case you can replace mousedown by onmouseover

```
canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', e => {
    let posX = scaleByPixelRatio(e.offsetX);
    let posY = scaleByPixelRatio(e.offsetY);
    let pointer = pointers.find(p => p.id == -1);
    if (pointer == null)
        pointer = new pointerPrototype();
    updatePointerDownData(pointer, -1, posX, posY);
});
```

Following is link of w3 school to learn more about this eventlistner.
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseover.asp

Upvote if answer was helpful.